# If child has class

Tags: jquery

I need to check which class my icon has in the following code, if it is present.

```
<li>
    <a href="#">link 1</a>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">link 2</a>
</li>
```

Seems pretty straight forward but I can't seem to be able to get it to work.

```
$(document).on('click', 'li a', function() {
    if ($(this).find('i').hasClass('.fa-caret-down')) {
        alert('down');
    } else if ($(this).find('i').hasClass('.fa-caret-up')) {
        alert('up');
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't use dot in `hasClass` method: `.hasClass('fa-caret-up')`

Comment: @antyrat You're right. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two mistakes.

1. You have to use `siblings()` as `find()` search for child elements.
2. In `hasClass()` you have to remove dot `.` from class.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'li a', function() {
  if ($(this).siblings('i').hasClass('fa-caret-down')) {
    alert('down');
  } else if ($(this).siblings('i').hasClass('fa-caret-up')) {
    alert('up');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="#">link 1</a>
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">link 2</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Or better still (for flexibility), `.closest('li').find('i').hasClass('fa-caret-up')`

Comment: Even better, consider using classes or `data-` attributes or similar to mark the entire `li` as `open` or `closed` (or whatever) – otherwise your web site **logic** is dependent on which icon (library) you are using – not great.

Answer (score 2):

You're targetting the `<a>` and asking for the `<i>` inside it (`this`). What you want to do is ask for `this.parent()` and proceed from there, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'li a', function() {
    if ($(this).parent().find('i').hasClass('fa-caret-down')) {
        alert('down');
    } else if ($(this).parent().find('i').hasClass('fa-caret-up')) {
        alert('up');
    }
});
```

ps: you could also target the li (instead of li a).